# Getting current date in JSTL EL and doing arithmetic on it

Tags: jsp, date, jstl, el, date-arithmetic

Without using scriptlets, what's the correct way for doing date arithmetic in JSP?

Here are examples what I'm trying to do:

1. Get current year (YYYY)
2. Subtract current year by one to get previous year (YYYY)

Thanks!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use [`<jsp:useBean>`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/syntaxref12-149806.pdf) to construct new [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). Use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) [`<fmt:formatDate>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatDate.html) to get the year out of it. Use [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) to substract it.

```
<%@taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date" />
<fmt:formatDate var="year" value="${now}" pattern="yyyy" />
<p>Current year: ${year}</p>
<p>Previous year: ${year - 1}</p>
```

Result:

> Current year: 2011
>
> Previous year: 2010

Note that the [pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for full year is `yyyy`, not `YYYY`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked Perfectly

Comment: BalusC's answers are awesome for the links to the reference material

Comment: You might need to use ```.toString()``` for ```{year-1}``` if you are passing it to ```.properties``` file or somewhere else which might add commas(eg: 2,010) considering it a number due to the arithmetic calculation we just did.