# Get previous year from the current one in a JSP page

Tags: jsp, date, jstl

Seems simple, but not for me. I can get the current year with:

```
<jsp:useBean id="date" class="java.util.Date" />
<fmt:formatDate value="${date}" pattern="yyyy" />
```

But I can't do a simple -1 in the resulting value because the operations dies there, as html text. I'd love to -1 the year from that ${date} but, well, it's a date.

I'm looking for a non-scriptlet, preferably JSTL solution.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949554/getting-current-date-in-jstl-el-and-doing-arithmetic-on-it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSTL converts values in the page based on appropriate [coercions rules between object and primitives](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2003/10/07/jstl1.html), so this should work:

```
<jsp:useBean id="date" class="java.util.Date" />
<fmt:formatDate value="${date}" pattern="yyyy" var="currentYear" />

<c:out value="${currentYear}" /> /
<c:out value="${currentYear - 1}" />
```

Or depending on your JSP version you can directly use `${currentYear}` and `${currentYear - 1}` without the `<c:out>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use EL.

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> 
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<jsp:useBean id="date" class="java.util.Date" />
<fmt:formatDate var="now" value="${date}" pattern="y" />  
Previous year is ${now - 1}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't see Bogdan's answer while typing mine.